# What is an example of a function that is uniformly continuous but not Lipschitz continuous, but not from R to R

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

Just for fun, I am looking for some interesting examples of functions that are uniformly continuous but not Lipschitz. I know the classic examples amongst functions from subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e square root and $x\sin(1/x)$).

Would love to see some examples of maps between more interesting spaces (so maybe I would put an emphasis on spaces that are not $\mathbb{R}^n$), although also open to learning some really cool/non-intuitive examples in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If the proof that the function in question is uniformly continuous but not Lipschitz is not particularly obvious, I would also appreciate a nudge in the right direction or some guidance towards it.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have right now an example, but I think it's possible to build one. Think in a function uniformly continuous on a bounded interval, but it's derivative not bounded on it. It will provided you with the desired example.

Comment: The square root function is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ (but maybe you're thinking of $\sqrt{|x|}$).

Comment: You are correct. I will edit my question. But the question still stands....

Comment: One obvious example with $1<n\in \Bbb N,$ the function $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ where $f(v)=\min (1,\sqrt {\|v\|}\;)$ with the Cartesian  (Euclidean) norm.